# Execute multiple transactions atomically on Ripple

Tags: transactions, ripple

I would like to execute two transactions, e.g. one from account A to account B and one from account B to itself, atomically, i.e. either include both transactions in the ledger or none of them. This is easily possible on UTXO based blockchains, like Bitcoin, as we can have multiple inputs in the same transaction. But this is not the case on account-based blockchains, like Ripple. Is it still somehow possible?